# panorama SelectionChanged not always fired

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a panorma control with three items.
I want to show an application bar on one of the items and hide the application bar on others.
Now the problem is : the one item on which I want to show the application bar SelectionChanged  is not called.

Here is my function:

```
private void panormaItemChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (((Panorama)sender).SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else {
                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

I had put my PanoramaItem in scrollview thats why it wasn't calling SelectionChanged listener!!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have taken event of `panormaItemChanged` instead of that take `PanormaSelectionChanged`. It would work.

XAML:

```
<phone:Panorama Title="my application" SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged">
```

cs:

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (((Panorama)sender).SelectedIndex)
    {

        case 0: // defines the first PanoramaItem
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            break;

        case 1: // second one
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
            break;

        case 2: // third one
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No,i am using SelectionChanged:<controls:Panorama  x:Name="SearchPan" Title="" Style="{StaticResource MainPanorama}" SelectionChanged="panormaItemChanged">